# How to set an Entity Framework query equal to a string

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm *very* new to Entity Framework. I'm trying to use it to query the database, and I want to set a string equal to the result of that query.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
string UserId = (db.StudentModel.Where(b => b.UserName == strCert)).ToString();
```

Now, obviously this sets UserId equal to the query. How do I set UserId equal to the *result*?

Comment: do you mean, how to get SQL query from LINQ query?

Comment: Am I incorrect in using the linq tag? I just want to use that query that I have above to get a cell from the database. The text in that cell is what I need UserId to store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this :

```
string UserId = db.StudentModel.FirstOrDefault(b => b.UserName == strCert).UserId;
```

or more safely :

```
var student = db.StudentModel.FirstOrDefault(b => b.UserName == strCert);
if(student != null) 
{
    string UserId = student.UserId;
    /* do something with UserId here */
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent implementation but I don't see the value added in line 2.

Comment: Two questions: 1) when I use this, it's giving me a 'cannot implicitly convert int to string' error - I don't even know what the int would be! 2) Can you explain why UserId goes at the end of the command?

Comment: It's starting to look like `UserId` is of type int rather than the inexplicable string type that OP's sample code includes :D

Comment: 1) you need to add `.ToString()` (edited my code as I didn't know before that `UserId` is of type `int`). 2) the query return a `StudentModel` -I guess the exact type- and you want only `UserId` property of that model, that's why `.UserId` at the end is required

Comment: WELL THAT'S EMBARRASSING. You're right. It's an int in the database. Much appreciated for pointing that out! hahaha

Comment: I'm getting a null reference exception with this, for some reason. Any idea on where to look for the culprit?

Comment: Personal preference `db.StudentModel.Where(x => x.UserName == strCert).FirstOrDefault().UserId`

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
db.StudentModel.FirstOrDefault(b => b.UserName == strCert).UserId
```

but would be better to get object and check for null

```
var user = db.StudentModel.FirstOrDefault(b => b.UserName == strCert);
```

Comment: you will need to check if query returns null to avoid exception